The difficulty of the question “why”
I often find the question “Why” in everyday conversation to be hard to answer logically.
Very often, when someone asks “Why X”, it seems to imply that there is something about a proposition or a state of affairs that requires explaining, but it is sometimes unclear, unknown or ambiguous what aspect of X seems to contradict normal expectations.
If someone asks why you went to the store, I do not think there is a “semantically correct” answer to this question if we tried to model it formally and logically. I think that a logically correct answer to the question would be the set of all causes for that event, which would include every causally dependent event in the history of the universe.
Maybe I myself do not perfectly know why I went to store (i.e. I was partially subconsciously driven to, and I have limited ability to observe and understand the mechanics of my own mind, so there may always be some obscurity in explaining one’s choices and actions), and if I rack my brains for reasons, the list would not be satisfactorily exhaustible.
Perhaps I had a spur of the moment whim to, partially because I felt like taking a walk, partially because I was considering that there might be something there that I might want to buy if I see it, partially because there might already be some useful things I have in mind that I want to buy.
It doesn’t really end there. The reason I wanted to go for a walk was because sometimes I like walking, and the weather was nice out, and I was finding the presence of the person I was around to be a little overbearing and wanted an excuse to get away. And I also wasn’t perfectly satisfied with the foods I had available to me with this person, so I wanted to eat some other foods of my choosing. Also, I like the ambience of that particular store, and it was late at night and it is one of the best options for “somewhere to go” in that location at that time. And so on.
There is not a logically clear way to enumerate “reasons” such as the above and then say, “There - you just reached the exhaustive list of reasons. This list fully and formally explains why you went to the store.” Of course, it can continue indefinitely as to why I have the personality and preferences I do, why I find that store’s ambience somewhat pleasing, and also why I came into existence the way I am, which can ultimately be traced back to the fact that a universe somehow can into being which apparently over time led to a person like me existing in a certain place and time.
This appears unlike some natural language questions like “What…” or “Who…”, which lend themselves better to being modeled in a simple formal system and where the answer is like a small, discrete collection of elements, perhaps just one, and there is a logical definition for whether the answer is right or wrong, or true or false.
Even if we can model the mechanics of human thought and intention as to what was going on in someone’s mind when they asked “Why” something (something like, they believe there are causal factors, but they don’t know what they are; perhaps “why” can always be rephrased as “What were the causal factors of this event?” or, “What are the logical preconditions of that proposition?”), the question isn’t what’s going on in people’s (perhaps irrational) minds, but what a logically clear interpretation of the question why is or should be, hence what a logically justified answer to this question in daily life can be.
For example, maybe, going off of what I said about logical preconditions above, we can imagine that since propositions form a lattice (in Boolean algebra), it may be possible to think of the question “why” as a way of determining gaps in the asker’s “worldview-lattice” (the propositions included in their “world”, the inferences they can draw from them) and then providing enough additional propositions from your own “world” (set/lattice of propositions) to efficiently generate propositions in their “world” that give them a subjective sense of “explainedness” (some threshold of dependent propositions existing for a given proposition). Then maybe there could be a deterministic way (an algorithm) to answer a question “why”, by first testing the most locally immediate preconditions to see which of them the asker recursively requires explanation for. But this requires an ordering on propositions to get a sense of “locality”.

While I'm not adverse to reading your musings on explanation, I'm not quite clear on if there's a question here Caesar Iulius?

Try mentally substituting for why: "What more general principles explain this specific principle?" As opposed to trying to find a causal relationship.

I think you're asking why humans have natural explanatory/metaphysical curiosity.  Or, why people seem to need logical explanations and metaphysics.  Which is ironically a "why" question.

We may just be running up on "why" being overloaded. The answer can be at least any of Aristotle's 4 factors (trees have leaves because they need sunlight; because their DNA says so; because they got nutrients to make them; because the matter took that form) or the gap-reasons you mention (because it's spring, because they're frost-hardy, because we didn't get around to stripping them. "Why"/"because" are 2 of those words that do a lot of work.

Heidegger dwells on the why in The Principle of Reason (1955-56), centering around some mystical poetry (page 35–36).

Whenever our cognition feels directed to render the reasons for what
it cognizes—the reason upon which and in which what is cognized firmly
stands as an object—then cognition is on the lookout for reasons to
render. This happens inasmuch as cognition asks: Why does what is
cognized exist, and why is it the way it is? In the "why?" we ask for
reasons. The strict formulation of the principle of reason—"Nothing is
without rendering its reasons"—can be formulated thus: Nothing is
without a why.
If we contrapose the short forms of each formulation, then we gain a
particular sharpness that affords us a still clearer view of the
principle of reason. On the one hand it reads: nothing is without
reason. On the other hand it reads: nothing is without a why. In
contradiction to this we now hear the following words:

The rose is without why: it blooms because it blooms, It pays no
attention to itself, asks not whether it is seen.

The verses are found in the first book of the spiritual poetry of
Angelus Silesius, which is entitled The Cherubic Wanderer: Sensual
Description of the Four Final Things.
The work first appeared in 1657. The verses carry the number 289 with
the heading "Without Why." Angelus Silesius, whose given name was
Johann Scheffler, doctor philosophiae et medicinae, by profession a
medical doctor, lived from 1624 to 1677 in Silesia. Leibniz
(1646-1716) was a younger contemporary of Angelus Silesius and was
familiar with The Cherubic Wanderer. Leibniz often speaks in his
writings and letters of Angelus Silesius. . . .



The rose is without why; it blooms because it blooms.

"Because"? Does this word not name the relationship to a ground by
dragging one in, so to speak? The rose—without why and yet not without
a because. So the poet contradicts himself and speaks obscurely.
Indeed the mystical consists in this sort of thing. But the poet
speaks clearly. "Why" and "because" mean different things. "Why" is
the word for the question concerning grounds. The "because" contains
the answer-yielding reference to grounds. The "why" seeks grounds. The
"because" conveys grounds. What is different here is the way in which
the relationship to grounds is represented. In the "why" the
relationship to grounds is one of seeking.

In the long run, the case of the ground of the living being is considered.  Here we have a situation like Descartes saying cogito ergo sum, and then asking "but why?".  Clearly there are no clues for Descartes' bare, doubting cogito.  As the cogito ergo sum, this is the first point of determination.  Incidentally, Heidegger would have it more like "Being-in-the-world thinks something", bringing both world and something into the initial determination.  Nevertheless, we ask "why being?".  But since being is not a thing we escape the requirement of rendering a reason, because the nihil est sine ratione, in the affirmative, applies only to things.  Being is found to be ground-less, abyssal (ab-grundtief).  In the indeterminacy of causality the determining point for the cogito is only cogito ergo sum.  No further ground for the being of oneself (or the grounding of the scientific method) is available, for all the other directions lead into indeterminate regress.

Thanks for the

I've often wondered why Heidegger couldn't write more clearly and concisely. If people understood even the last sentence of your Answer, it would save no end of trouble.

@ScottRowe Yes, I think it's useful to emphasise that Heidegger's project actually aims to ground science; it's not anti-realist, (it just digs deeper).

@ScottRowe e.g. "Our analysis then pursues the existential-temporal possibility that circumspective concern may be modified into a discovering of entities within-the-world in the sense of certain possibilities of scientific research, and discovering them 'merely' by looking at them." GA 2, 351

Can't see why anyone would have the slightest difficulty... :-) Isn't the point of writing, to be understood? But again, if people grasped the last sentence of your Answer, just staggering amounts of wasted time and conflict would be avoided.

@ScottRowe Ha ha. He builds up a system designed to describe the indefinable. This seems to be the main difficulty for the analytic camp. E.g. in SEP: Grounding, Heidegger is only referred to once, re. Casati who says "the two assumptions endorsed by Heidegger lead to the ineffability of the ground, but they also lead to an aporia. … because, exactly in saying that being is ineffable, we say something about it. In other terms, exactly in saying that being is not an entity, being is an entity because we refer to it. … namely a contradiction."

I reply to this point via Derrida's 1964 Heidegger: The Question of Being & History, p. 51-53, i.e. "the expression Sein is not only an infinitive but a verbal substantive ... It consolidates it and makes it into something. / Should we abandon a grammatical form that is so threatening for the right thinking of being, a thinking that is neither a concept nor a thinking of a being? Heidegger pretends to think so but only in order to show that simply renouncing this form, simply erasing this word that the verbal substantive is, would obscure the problem still further. … What would happen if,

"giving up on the grammatical form of the verbal substantive in philosophical discourse, we had to limit ourselves to the other forms? ... In that case, one would say: being? — I know nothing about it. I do not know what that means, primarily because I’ve never come across it and no one will ever come across it. The pre-comprehension Heidegger talks about at the beginning of Sein und Zeit is in this case merely an incomprehension. I understand what being means only when being comes to determine something or is determined by something, when I say I am, and you are, and he or it is, and so on."
